How to draw curve dashed line with point icons and titles in flutter?
In my flutter app i have to draw curve line with image or icon and text like bellow image.

So how i can create UI in flutter as image?
This is my code as below.
class CurveLineMyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Widget? startWidget;
  final Widget? endWidget;
  final Widget? midWidget;

  CurveLineMyPainter({this.startWidget, this.endWidget, this.midWidget});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6)
      ..strokeWidth = 1.0
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round;

    Path path = Path();
    path.moveTo(size.width / 2 + 20, size.height * 0.1); // Start position
    path.cubicTo(
        size.width * -0.4 + 20,
        size.height * 0.9, // Control point 1
        size.width * 1 + 80,
        size.height * 0.15, // Control point 2
        size.width * 0.8 - 80,
        size.height * 0.95); // End point

    drawDashedPath(canvas, paint, path);

    // Draw circular containers at starting, ending, and midpoint of the line
    drawCircularContainer(canvas, size.width / 2 + 20, size.height * 0.1);
    drawCircularContainer(canvas, size.width * 0.8 - 80, size.height * 0.95);

    PathMetrics pathMetrics = path.computeMetrics();
    for (PathMetric pathMetric in pathMetrics) {
      Tangent tangent =
          pathMetric.getTangentForOffset(pathMetric.length * 0.65)!;
      drawCircularContainer(canvas, tangent.position.dx, tangent.position.dy);
    }
  }

  void drawDashedPath(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, Path path) {
    const double dashWidth = 5.0;
    const double dashSpace = 5.0;

    PathMetrics pathMetrics = path.computeMetrics();
    for (PathMetric pathMetric in pathMetrics) {
      double distance = 0.0;
      while (distance < pathMetric.length) {
        final double start = distance;
        final double end = distance + dashWidth;

        // Limit the end point to the path length
        final double finalEnd =
            end > pathMetric.length ? pathMetric.length : end;

        canvas.drawPath(
          pathMetric.extractPath(start, finalEnd),
          paint,
        );
        distance = finalEnd + dashSpace; // Skip space
      }
    }
  }

  void drawCircularContainer(Canvas canvas, double x, double y) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Constants.COLOR_BORDER
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(x, y), 5.0, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}

Here i have created simple Circular containers using drawCircularContainer() but i want to create custom widgets which i pass from startWidget, endWidget and midWidget.

use CustomPaint widget

i have already draw the line but i am not able to add icons and text at that points, how i can do it?

I will edit the question, so viewers can see what i have done.

no, you cannot "draw" widgets in CustomPainter - you need Stack / CustomMultiChildLayout / Flow  to position your Widgets at any particular place
